# GET Request 401 (Unauthorized) android volley

Tags: java, android, authentication, android-volley, wordpress-rest-api

I'm sending get request to the server to get list of all users , I'm using wordpress rest api end point ,when sending the request with headers authorization token i get 401 response 
note: JsonParserVolley is a helper class where i pass parameters to create volley request and add headers and params

```
   jsonParserVolley.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer " +access_token);
          jsonParserVolley.executeRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://taqoh.com/wum/wp-json/wp/v2/users", new VolleyCallback() {
              @Override
              public void notifySuccess(String response) {
                  Log.i("idid",response);
              }

              @Override
              public void notifyError(VolleyError error) {


                  Log.i("ididd",error.toString());
              }
          });

      }
        }
```

error message:

2019-07-17 15:51:28.812 23732-23784/com.example.toqah04 E/Volley: [1648] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://taqoh.com/wum/wp-json/wp/v2/users/